# ajax datatype json jquery success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../ajax/deletestudent.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        window.location.reload(true);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert(data); // Optional
        window.location = '../pages/studentdata.php';
    }
});

$deletedstudent = "Deleted";
    echo json_encode(array(
    'message' => $deletedstudent
));
```

I have this ajax above and the echo from php file. From the ajax i have an `alert` and a `console.log` both of them uses data as parameter. My question is why does in the console.log the output is `Object {message: "Deleted."}` but in alert the output is `[object Object]`. But they both use same parameter. I am expecting both of them will return `Deleted.`. Why is this happening any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Console behaves slightly differently depending on the browser. Some make its output more friendly than others. `alert` has stayed pretty basic AFAIK as it's an archaic, obsolete way to debug.

Comment: i was using the alert as prompt messages such saying that the record has been deleted.

Comment: if you do indeed want to block the whole UI, then that is a good use-case for `alert`, `prompt` or `confirm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log something to the console, the console gives more verbose output than alert does. It looks like you actually want to do `alert(data.message)`.

Comment: i see..i thought they are just the same

Answer (score 2):

**The basic answer:** `console.log` is smart but `alert` is not smart.

---

**More detailed answer**

`console.log` logs the object with it's properties and (depending on what browser you are using) other helpful information (such as what line the `console.log` was called from).

`alert`, on the other hand takes whatever is passed in and runs a [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on it

Take this example:

```
var myObj = {
    foo: 'bar',
    xxx: 'yyy'
};
```

`console.log`ing it should give you the object with all of it's properties as seen in this picture:

[image: console.log of myObj]

`alert` will give you a `toString` of an object which is the string `[object Object]`.

***Note:*** Any object that you `toString` will come out to be `[object Object]`.

Comment: excellent explanation sir i would love to tick both answers if possible but i will have to tick the first answer i will just up the answer